# django - invoice form - validate the sub totals and net total before save

Tags: django, validation, invoice, inline-formset

I have an invoice form made up of two models - Invoice & InvoiceItem - with the help of inlineformset_factory.

I have the following jquery snippet to compute the individual totals and net total by reading the price,quantity,tax of each item.

```
function calculateSubTotal(obj){
    subTotal = 0 

    parentDiv = obj.closest('.formset')

    rate=parseFloat($(parentDiv).find('.rate').val())
    quantity=parseInt($(parentDiv).find('.quantity').val())
    tax=$(parentDiv).find('.tax option:selected').html()//.

    tax=tax.match(/\d+/);
    if(tax)
        tax=parseFloat(tax[0],10)
    else
        return

    if(!isNaN(rate) && !isNaN(quantity) && $.isNumeric(tax)){
        subTotal = rate*quantity*(100+tax)/100
        $(parentDiv).find('.total').val(subTotal)
    }
}

function calculateTotal() {
    subTotal=0
    $('.total').each(function(){
        //console.log($(this).id)
        console.log($(this).val())
        val=parseFloat($(this).val())
        subTotal+=val
    });
    if(!isNaN(subTotal))
        $('#id_total').val(subTotal)
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formset .form-control').on("blur",function(e){
        calculateSubTotal(this);
        calculateTotal();
    });

});
```

**Now, I "believe", I need to make all these calculations on the server-side before save**, in order to prevent any manual correction/error by the user in the form. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

**How do I proceed here?**

Here's my form_valid() of CreateView.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    item_formset = context['item_formset']
    with transaction.atomic():
        form.instance.invoice_type=self.kwargs['invoice_type']
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        #self.object.save()
        if item_formset.is_valid():
            forms = item_formset.save(commit=False)

            for form in forms:
                **#calculate sub-total and assign net-total to parentform.instance.total**
            item_formset.instance = self.object
            item_formset.save()

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a lot of trial-and-errors around models's save(), post-save signals, form's clean() etc. and finally got something that works.

Here's how it looks right now.

1. ***First***, use `InvoiceItemForm`'s  `clean()` method to make sure that the total of each row is correct

   ```
   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data=super(InvoiceItemForm, self).clean()

       total=cleaned_data.get('total')
       if total:
           tax=cleaned_data.get('tax')
           calculated_total=price*(100+tax.rate)*quantity/100
           if calculated_total != total:
               raise forms.ValidationError({'total':["Total is incorrect."]})
           return  cleaned_data
   ```
2. ***Next***, under CreateViews's form_valid() method, iterate through each form in the formset and sum the individual totals. Compare this to the total value of the main form.

   ```
   with transaction.atomic():
       form.instance.invoice_type=self.kwargs['invoice_type']
       self.object = form.save(commit=False)

       if item_formset.is_valid() == False:
           return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,item_formset=item_formset ))

       subTotal=0
       i=0
       for f in item_formset.forms:
           subTotal += float(f.data['item-'+str(i)+'-total'])
               i=i+1
       if subTotal!= float(form.data['total']):
           form.add_error('total', "Total is incorrect.")
           return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,item_formset=item_formset ))
   ```

(Any possible corrections/simplifications are welcome)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way would probably to create custom model methods for `Invoice` and `InvoiceItem` then call them on your form's `save()` or in your view's `form_vaild()`.

An example `models.py`:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey()
    date = models.DateField()
    total = models.DecimalField()

    def process_invoice(self):
        items = InvoiceItem.objects.filter(invoice=self)
        for item in items:
            ... process item ....
            item.save()
        self.total = InvoiceItem.objects.filter(invoice=self).values('line_total').aggregate(tot=Sum('line_total')['tot']
        ... add whatever other logic you need ...
        self.save()
```

Then in your `form_valid` you would call the method by `self.object.process_invoice()`.

Comment: Thanks. But, would there be InvoiceItem objects before saving an Invoice object?